# Default Value for XSD

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060190/xml-schema-setting-a-default-value-for-a-complextype) here asks about default values specified in an XSD file. Basically you can say the field "foo" defaults to value "bar"

What I want to know... is it possible to have a field default as the value in another field? If field "foo" is "bar" and "otherfoo" is empty, can I say it's default is the value in "foo"... something along the lines of:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="button" type="button"/>
  <xs:complexType name="button">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="label1" type="xs:string" default="Go"/>
    <xs:attribute name="label2" type="xs:string" default=label1/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

<button id="1"/>
```

Where Label1 defaults to "Go"... Label2 defaults to the value in Label1.

Goal is to remove redundancy such as:

```
<Field Name="State" DataSourceField="State" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, in fact XML Schema provides little or no support for cross-element dependencies (including validation).

Comment: I hadn't seen anything suggesting it was possible, so I'm not surprised... makes me sad because now I have to edit code to get'er'done.

Comment: I'm not convinced a schema is the right place for this kind of thing anyway. It's easy enough if you're reading the file using XSLT to program the defaults at that level.

Comment: Schematron http://schematron.com can be used to encode those sort of business rules and validate XML documents.