# xld schema: How to force a default value for

Tags: xml, xsd

I have defined the following xsd types:

```
<xs:complexType name="parentType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="att" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="childType">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="parentType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="att" type="xs:string" default="foo" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can guess, I want to override an element of a type by giving a default value 'foo' and changing its occurrence range (like I would do in java).

Unfortunately, when writing `<childType />`, I am expected to have an element with a `att="foo"`, but my XML validator says: `The content of element 'childType' is not complete. One of '{att}' is expected.` It seems the override of the element definition did not work.

Did I miss something? Do you know how to override element definitions in XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what you did with "extension":

[image: XSD Diagram]

A restriction might work, but then it may go against the reason you placed a default - which could be different that your expectation (see [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060190/xml-schema-setting-a-default-value-for-a-complextype) for an explanation).

```
<xs:complexType name="childType"> 
    <xs:complexContent> 
        <xs:restriction base="parentType"> 
            <xs:sequence> 
                <xs:element name="att" type="xs:string" default="foo" /> 
            </xs:sequence> 
        </xs:restriction> 
    </xs:complexContent> 
</xs:complexType>
```

The thing is, you cannot make the element optional in the restriction. The default would still work; the difference being an empty element will be considered as foo.

You may have something like this instead:

```
<xs:complexType name="parentType"> 
    <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="att" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/> 
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 
<xs:complexType name="childType"> 
    <xs:complexContent> 
        <xs:restriction base="parentType"> 
            <xs:sequence> 
                <xs:element name="att" type="xs:string" default="foo" /> 
            </xs:sequence> 
        </xs:restriction> 
    </xs:complexContent> 
</xs:complexType>
```

You can move the default to the parent, if you want - it all depends on what you're really trying to achieve here. I really think you've confused how **default** works for elements; it seems you've expected more like how it works for attribute.