# Defining default value for complex type in XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xsd that contains the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyDataType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" fixed="9999" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="MessageType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="Data" type="MyDataType"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

So this fragment is valid:

```
<Message>
    <Data>true</Data>
</Message>
```

Where Message is defined as being of type MessageType. But what I'd like to do is give clients the ability to omit the Data element:

```
<Message></Message>
```

(Or the equivalent self-closed element)

Semantically, kinda like:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyDataType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:boolean" default="true">
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" fixed="9999" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

With the default added to the extension. Doesnt work though....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Schema: Setting a default value for a complexType?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060190/xml-schema-setting-a-default-value-for-a-complextype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve what you want.

More so, assuming you move the default="true" to the Data element declaration, and make Data optional (by adding minOccurs="0")... there is a difference between how it works for elements and attributes... quoting from the [Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints): *"Default attribute values apply when attributes are missing, and default element values apply when elements are empty."*

So the closest you might get is to allow for `<Message><Data/></Message>`, in which case the default value of "true" becomes available through PSVI.